# Как избавиться от Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in

Tags: php, sendmail

Как избавиться от ошибки

```
Warning: mail(): Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header in .......
```

Вроде бы она возникает из-за двойных символов переноса

```
/n/n
```

В коде своего письма я исправил все двойные переносы на одинарные

Я пытаюсь отправить HTML письмо с картинками и вложениями.

Answer (score 0):

PHP скрипт отправки можете выложить? т.к. такая ошибка

> Multiple or malformed newlines found in additional_header

может быть и из за некорректного `headers`

Comment: Добавил код отправки письма